# In Selenium IDE how do I test the delete functionality like it deletes some things while running script

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am testing a functionality of module which has add and delete user functionality, I recorded a script to delete data but how do I cross verify that deletion has takes place , that particular user gets deleted, one is by verify the success message but do we verify other way like that user is not present so it means it gets deleted successfully

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what object it is you are deleting.
In your example you said that you delete a user. You could try to log in with the deleted user, and expect (verify) that the application responds with some error message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add more information on what exactly you are trying to acheive ?

If you are willing to test the non existance of an DOM object after deletion, there is **assertElementNotPresent**

If you willing to test non existence of data, as saied above, after deleting, query again the data to ensure that the data does not exists anymore.

If this not answers your question, please provide more info on your need

Comment: i had a script in which I add 1 user, then edit it and after this delete that user, now I want to cross verify  that the user is successfully deleted., my question is how do I check the deletion has been done that user does not exist anymore

Comment: This script is a selenium script? By the way; after deletion try to login with user deleted and you should receive an error message. Test that message in selenium ide